# ObjectType not detecting the right Enum file in WPF (XAML)

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml

The title may be misleading, but I don't really know the exact term for it.

So in the solution, there is a folder called `Enums` that contains 3 files. (see below pic). One of them is `SudokuDifficultyType.cs`. Inside there, there is basically nothing but this.

```
namespace Sudoku_w__SW_WPF.Enums
{
    public enum SudokuDifficultyType
    {
        Easy,
        Medium,
        Hard,
        Impossible
    }
}
```

So in `MainWindow.xaml`, I want to access these values. So I added
`xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:Sudoku_w__SW_WPF.Enums;assembly=Sudoku_w__SW_WPF"`
and tried to access by

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="SudokuDifficultyEnumValues" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type enums:SudokuDifficultyType}">
                <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
                    <x:Type TypeName="enums:SudokuDifficultyType"/>
                </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            </ObjectDataProvider>
```

(btw, x refers to `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`)

---

When I compiled this, It gave errors saying

> Error : The type reference cannot find a public type named 'SudokuDifficultyType'. Line 13 Position 140.
>   Error : The name "SudokuDifficultyType" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Sudoku_w_SW_WPF.Enums;assembly=Sudoku_w__SW_WPF". Line 15

Any ideas on how to make this work?

Additional information:

- Assembly name : `Sudoku_w__SW_WPF`
- Default namespace : `Sudoku_w__SW_WPF`

Any help will be appreciated. (I tried fixing for different ways for 5 hrs)
Thank you.

[image: My current VS]

Above pic is my current work in `VS2017`, some part censored for personal reasons.

---

[image: bigger view of error/solutionexplorer]
This is a bigger view of Error List / Solution Explorer

Comment: Isn't Sudoku_w__SW_WPF.Enums the right namespace? In your XAML, you wrote Sudoku_w_SW_WPF.Enums (and underline is missing after w_

Comment: Where did I write wrong?

Comment: at this line : xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:Sudoku_w_SW_WPF.Enums;assembly=Sudoku_w__SW_WPF, check if namespace is spelled correctly

Comment: thank you for helping, but i mistyped that in SO

Comment: Me too. Using the namespace declaration in my answer should work.

Comment: yeah, i wonder why. seems like a project-level problem

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the namespace is spelled correctly and remove the `assembly` part if the `enum` is defined in the same assembly as your XAML:

```
xmlns:enums="clr-namespace:Sudoku_w__SW_WPF.Enums"
```

Comment: I removed, attached, did everything esp. with the assembly but keep getting this error `Error : The name "SudokuDifficultyType" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:Sudoku_w__SW_WPF.Enums". Sudoku_w__SW_WPF

Comment: Did you try to copy the namespace from your .cs file? Do that and try to build.

Comment: yeah, I did but no luck.